# Pause.sty CTAN in article class

Tags: pdftex, article, pause, slideshow

In the following code, I would like to create a pause between the items 1 and 2.
For this , I would like to use the package pause.sty available here:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/ppower4

As you can notice by yourself, the code compiles with pdfLatex without error but pause doesn't make what I expected: to create two pages, the first page showing only the first item and the second page showing the two items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{0.4in}{0.24in}{.24in}{.5in}
\screensize{6.24in}{8.5in}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\newslide}[1]{\vfill\null \hfill \theslide \end{slide}\\
\begin{slide}\vspace{-0.22in}\hspace{-0.4in}\colorbox{thistle}{\begin{minipage}{8.5in}\hspace{0.24in}\large
\textsc{ \color{white} #1}\end{minipage}}\vfill }

\usepackage{pause}
%\usepackage{texpause}
%\usepackage{background}
%\usepackage{mpmulti}
%\usepackage{pp4link}

\begin{document}
\begin{slide} 
\begin{itemize}  
\item 1 \pause
\item 2   
\end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a question: Do you try to produce a screen presentation? If yes, you could have a look at beamer that has this functionality on board.

Comment: Yes sort of presentation, but I would like not to use beamer class but the article class (it's easier to copy paste from an article written in the article class)

Comment: The packages relies on the `ppower4` program, you need to run that on your file to generate the finished PDF.  (I've never heard of this package before, but that much is clear after glancing at the manual.)

Comment: Note also that the software is from 2002 and may not run with more recent pdf versions.

Answer (score 3):

As  Torbjørn T. mentioned, you need to (download and) invoke the `PPower4` program as a postprocessor on the generated pdf file. Besides this, internally the tool runs a pdf parser that cannot handle pdf 1.5 or higher, which is currently the default for `pdflatex`. Therefore, you should set the pdf version in your document to 1.4 or less.

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfminorversion=4
\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}
[rest of your MWE]
```

`pdflatex yourfile.tex` (possibly multiple times as always)

`java -jar pp4p.jar yourfile.pdf finalpresentation.pdf`

Open with any pdf reader. Result:

[image]

Note that generally `beamer` is probably more suitable for making nice presentations (and definitely better supported). Note also that a presentation is very different from an article from the point of view of the audience - try to limit copy-pasting content as much as possible.